# WPF Button - how to bind a "click" attribute to a function?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind a function with a "click" attribute of a Button,

**A CLICK ATTRIBUTE, NOT A COMMAND. THANK YOU.**

here is what I tried to do:

The Xaml Code line:

```
<Button Background="{Binding Path=motionColor}" Click="{Binding MotionButton_Click}" />
```

The c# relevant code: (which inside the binded object, and not the window class)

```
public void MotionButton_Click(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        SendPacket(cockpitType, (byte)Index.Motion, MotionValue);
        setMotion(3);       
}
```

Some notes:

- The background binding works just fine.
- I have tried to do it as "Path=MotionButton_Click", not working either.
- Here is the error I get:

> Error 1   Click="{Binding MotionButton_Click}" is not valid. '{Binding
> MotionButton_Click}' is not a valid event handler method name. Only
> instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid. Line
> 50 Position 94.   c:\users\dp27317\documents\visual studio
> 2010\Projects\GenericSoundMotion\GenericSoundMotion\MainWindow.xaml   50  94  GenericSoundMotion

- Not sure if important but the binded collection is "ObservableCollection" of "public class GenericPanel".

All I want is that when I press on that button, the "MotionButton_Click" function will run. Everything that will make it work is a blessing, even dirty solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: The MotionButton_Click function is inside the binded class, "GenericPanel".

Comment: is it MVVM application?

Comment: Yes, it's a MVVM application.

Comment: *Sigh*... It's not a command, it's a click... Believe me, I search real deep before asking a question. I would appreciate if you cancel that downvote.

Comment: Click event is for when using code behand, Command for when using MVVM. Both are equivalent of each other. If you want to really use the click (I wouldn't see why as you don't use the eventargs) then use a trigger.

Comment: Still, I don't see how it's a duplicate of the other question, using trigget might be an answer. Not a justified downvote.

Comment: Well so you guys made it a duplicate question even though it's not. Great.

Comment: *Sigh...* The Click event is not a bindable property. Accept that fact, then bind the Button's Command property to a command in your view model.

Comment: So the answer to my question is "Forget about click attribute, go for command", as andreask answered me. What it has to do with duplicating is beyond me I guess.

Comment: Quite obviously, the answer to the duplicate question shows you how to bind a Button's Command property to a command in a view model. Exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: Since the answers are the same, the question is a duplicate, I understand now, There are no different questions with the same answer, make sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a WPF button, `Click` is an event, so you can't bind anything to it. You can either take a look at commanding (since binding to the button's `Command` property will have the same effect as specifying a `Click` event handler: a method that is invoked when clicking the button), or move the event handler to the window class, and call the method in the binded class from there, e.g. by referncing the window's `DataContext`.

Comment: It's not working because the method is not in the window class, it's in the binded object, there is no other way?

Comment: So I've tried to make it happen with the "Command="{Binding Path=MotionButton_Click}"" attribute, the function doesn't run on click but there are no errors, any idea?

Comment: The method to be invoked must be declared as `ICommand` instead of an event handler. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752308(v=vs.100).aspx or some other commanding tutorial for details about how to declare commands!